# 「ブラウザ表示時」表示ボタンによる抽出が不用意に解除される。

Tags: バグ, 却下, モバイル

例示します。

質問一覧を表示し、任意の検索テーマやタグで絞り込みます。

加えて、画面右上隅の「表示」ボタンより
表示項目を「未解決」に絞り込みます。

最後に、更なる過去質問歴表示のために
ベージ表示を過去のものへ遷移させます。

すると、先の「表示」ボタンよりの抽出が崩れ
選出されていないベタな内容に変わります。

Comment: 通常の PC 表示では「表示」というボタンは描画されないはずなのですが、どのようなデバイスで閲覧なさっていますか？　可能であれば [edit] してスクリーンショットを添付してみてくださいませんでしょうか。

Comment: 失礼致しました、情報欠損を　謝罪致します、私に付きましては、iPhone最新機、最新iOS環境、ブラウザは、Firefox、サファリて、観覧させて頂いております。　重ねて　不手際を、お詫び　致します。　後、スクリーンショットですが、動画でも　構わないでしょうか？　サイト機能内では　対応不当な、場合、此方で　別にご、提示も、可能かと　思われます。

Comment: 「最新」だと時間によってバージョンが変わってしまうため、特定のバージョンを指定していただきたいです。

Comment: UI につきまして、PC 版の表示ではなくてモバイル版の表示を見てらっしゃるようです。モバイル版の表示であれば「表示」というリンクが描画されていることを確認しました。ただし、私の環境ではページを変えてもデザインは崩れませんでした。特定の操作に由来しているか、端末固有の問題かもしれません。モバイル版の見た目が改善されることはなかなか無いため、PC 版を見ていただく方が解決としては早いかもしれませんね……。（私の環境：Pixel 4a、Android 11、Google Chrome 89）

Comment: 其の様ですね。

既に　表示が、
変わっている　事を、
此方でも　確認しました。
"

唯、

表示が　ころっと、
変わっているため、
再燃性確認は　まだ、
怠っている　状態です、

済みません。

Comment: 酷いなー、
"
再現性は　ありますよ。
"
"
此方を、
"
https://1drv.ms/v/s!AjviygfJDgV_439GQEGA0g3uKoSg
'
ベージを　おくると、
タブ数が　明らかに、
増えて　いますよね？

Answer (score 3):

iPhone は持ち合わせていないので、PC の Firefox で開発ツールを使って試してみました。

コメントで示された動画を見てみると、任意のタグが付けられた質問一覧を表示した状態から表示を「未解決」に切り替えたのに、ページのリロードがかかると「票」のソートに変わってしまう、という現象は確かに再現しました。

同様の問題は MSE などの関連サイトでも発生していますが、一方で英語版ではそもそも一覧表示の項目が他と違っており、この辺りが原因となっていそうです。

具体的には、日本語版や MSE では "未解決 (Unanswered)" というフィルタがあるのに対して、英語版では "Unanswered" のフィルタが存在しません。

恐らくバグと思われるので、スタッフによる調査・対応待ちになると思います。

#### 実際の表示例

**日本語版:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**MSE:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**英語版:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: MSE にも報告済みです。 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363806

Comment: cubick様、
"
追認証　有難うございます。

Answer (score 2):

モバイル版での作業を優先していないため、本リクエストを[却下](/questions/tagged/%e5%8d%b4%e4%b8%8b)といたします。私たちはサイトのより多くの領域をレスポンシブデザインにし、最終的には（タイムラインや公式なプランとしてはまだありませんが）モバイル版を廃止する予定です。